# Run a specific scalatest test via maven command line

Tags: scala, maven, scalatest

I have a scalatest file

```
// MyDefaultTest.scala
import collection.mutable.Stack
import org.scalatest._

class StackSpec extends FlatSpec {
  "A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
    val stack = new Stack[Int]
    stack.push(1)
    stack.push(2)
    assert(stack.pop() === 2)
    assert(stack.pop() === 1)
  }

  it should "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
    val emptyStack = new Stack[String]
    intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
      emptyStack.pop()
    }
  }
}
```

My project uses Maven. I want to, from the command line, run ONLY "A Stack should pop values in last-in-first-out order"

How can I do this?

So far, I have only figured out how to run just the file:

> mvn test -DwildcardSuites=com.package.whatever.MyStupidTest

scalatest [has options for a single test](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner), but that is not [a maven command](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin).

Comment: If anybody is still curious, I could not find a way. I ended up needing to make my own Scalatest runner anyways, and implemented the cmd into there... not exactly a fun solution!

Comment: Do you have a code sample for this solution anywhere like on Github?
I've hit the same problem.